# Why does the code for initializing Spark Context vary widely between different sources?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I know that I need to initialize Spark Context to create resilient distributed datasets (RDDs) in PySpark. However, different sources give different code for how to do so. To resolve this once and for all, what is the right code?

1) Code from Tutorials Point:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyspark/pyspark_sparkcontext.htm

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local", "First App")
```

2) Code from Apache:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#resilient-distributed-datasets-rdds

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
```

Then, later down the page, there is:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master)
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

These are just two examples. I can list more, but the main problem for me is the lack of uniformity for something so simple and basic. Please help and clarify.

Comment: It's all the same thing. You can start with default config like in `1)`, then you can pass a configuration using `SparkConf` like `2)`

Comment: I have two questions: A) What happens if I don't run SparkConf? B) What happens if I don't specify 'local' and 'First App' in SparkContext?

Comment: A) If you don't run `SparkConf` it will go to defaults, but you need to remove `conf=conf` from `SparkContext`.
B) If you don't specify `local`, it will still go with `local`

Comment: Thanks. Also, C) the documentation for SparkContext does not have the phrase "First App". What does it do? D) When you say "local", what is it referring to? Is it referring to whether the Spark application should be local or done on a cluster of computers?

Comment: If you say local, you're using your local host resources. When you specify a master node IP address of the spark cluster you use the cluster resources. And when you don't specify an app name, it could be left blank or spark could ne creating a random name

Comment: Would you like to put your responses into an answer, so that I can mark it as a solution and give you credit for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1)

In `local[N]` - N is the maximum number of cores can be used in a node at any point of time. This will use your local host resources.

In cluster mode (when you specify a Master node IP) you can set `--executor-cores N`. It means that each executor can run a maximum of N tasks at the same time in an executor.

### 2)

And when you don't specify an app name, it could be left blank or spark could ne creating a random name. I am trying to get the source code for [`setAppName()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkConf.setAppName) but not able to find any meat